# Theme.AppCompact Issue when creating AlertDialog on a listView with Android Studio

Tags: android

I am creating an App which pulls data from the (sadly closing) Parse database, presenting it on list. I want to set a clicker on the list that when you click on an item would bring up an Alert Dialog, with a Yes/No confirmation which would then lead into a text input.

I currently have this code for the listclicking/alert handler.

```
public void getClicker(){
        list.setClickable(true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(ListPull.this, o.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setTitle("Confirm");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Input Found Location");
                        // Set up the input
                        final EditText input = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        builder.setView(input);
                        // Set up the buttons
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                foundinput = input.getText().toString();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

But this always kicks out the logcat error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:310)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:76)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:213)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
                                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
                                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
                                                                                         at com.example.sammercer.muskateersfinal.ListPull$4.onItemClick(ListPull.java:262)
                                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3891)
                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3656)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
```

I have checked all of the Themes, and have now set them to Theme.AppCompact, but it is still giving the error. As well as having to test the clicker and finding out that it is correct and works, as I can make it produce a Toast of the string that I have clicked on

Comment: Do not use application context for inflating views, constructing views or constructing dialogs. `new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())` is killing it. `Context context = view.getContext()` may be a good choice.

Comment: I found the best way of doing it was to place `view.getContext()` inside of `new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())` but it completely worked thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use application context for inflating views, constructing views or constructing dialogs. `new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())` is killing it.

`Context context = view.getContext()` may be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly I just ended up putting `view.getContext()` inside of `AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())`